# Trouble Cascading in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to set up a cascading select box in Rails. I am using [dynamic-select-boxes](https://github.com/bmarcot/dynamic-select-boxes) as an example. For some reason I can't get it to work correctly. When I make a new selection in my drop down, WEBrick shows a 404 Not Found error for ActiveRecord.

The exact error is:

```
Started GET "/estimates/update_areas?product_type_id=1&_=1446822835903" for 50.17.182.190 at 2015-11-06 16:05:23 +0000
Cannot render console from 50.17.182.190! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by EstimatesController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"product_type_id"=>"1", "_"=>"1446822835903", "id"=>"update_areas"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."name" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Estimate Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "estimates".* FROM "estimates" WHERE "estimates"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "estimates"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)


ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Estimate with 'id'=update_areas):
  app/controllers/estimates_controller.rb:9:in `show'
```

For some reason the request is being routed to the 'show' method in my controller and I can't figure out why.

The update_areas method inside of my estimates_controller.rb:

```
  def update_areas
    @areas = Area.where("product_type_id = ?", params[:product_type_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

The relevant routes are:

```
  resources :estimates
  get 'estimates/new/update_areas', to: 'estimates#update_areas'
```

My estimate.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#product_type_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_areas',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        product_type_id: $("#product_type_select option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic area select OK!")
```

and my update_areas.js.coffee

```
$("#areas_select").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @areas)) %>")
```

Any idea why the ajax request is being routed to the wrong route?

UPDATE 1
Okay, I still haven't solved this, but just thought I would add a little more information. I commented out the **resources :estimates** line from my routes file and left the line **get 'estimates/update_areas/', to: 'estimates#update_areas'** in the routes file and everything works like expected. As soon as I uncomment the estimates resource, it fails.

With the estimates resource uncommented I get a line like

```
Parameters: {"product_type_id"=>"1", "_"=>"1447260557304", "id"=>"update_areas"}
```

in WEBrick. Without the resource I get

```
Parameters: {"product_type_id"=>"2", "_"=>"1447260557305"
```

which is what I expect. Why, when I add the resource line in the routes file is an ID parameter passed all of a sudden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally got this to work.

In my routes.rb the estimates resource became:

```
  resources :estimates do
    get 'update_areas', on: :new
  end
```

and my estimates.js.coffee became:

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#product_type_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax
      url:'/estimates/new/update_areas',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'script',
      data: {
        product_type_id: $("#product_type_select option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus} #{errorThrown}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic area select OK!")
```

This accepted the appropriate parameters and updated the target select box. Hope this helps someone else some day.